# Logstash kafka topic as part of elasticsearch indexname

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I want to use kafka topic as part of es-indexname. Here is my example, but this does not work:

```
input {
  kafka {    
    ...
    decorate_events => true
  }
}

filter {    
  mutate {
    add_field => {"[@metadata][index]" => "[kafka][topic]"}
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "kafka-%{[@metadata][index]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    ...
  }
}
```

Can someone find the problem in this logstash.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hello this is working config:

```
input {
  kafka {    
    ...
    decorate_events => true
  }
}

filter {    
  mutate {
    add_field => {"[@metadata][index]" => "%{[kafka][topic]}"}
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "kafka-%{[@metadata][index]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    ...
  }
}
```